# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) while my backend accepts the request

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Is it possible to use 2 patch on express ? cause I'm having trouble on my routes. my add product works perfectly. but the other one is giving me 404 status on client side. I tried to console my req.body and the data was accepted.. I'm kinda confused what's the problem in here.

here's my server side routes.

```
router.patch('/admin/collections/all/:id', addOwnerProducts); 
router.patch('/admin/collections/view/:id', updateOwnerProduct);
```

I'm not sure if the problem was one client side or server side. I'm currently using axios for my request and here's the axios for my update product.

```
export const editItem = (admin,productname,price,quantity,categoryfilter,description,timestamp) => api.patch(`/admin/collections/view/${admin}`,
    {
        store: [
            {
                productname: productname,
                price: price,
                quantity: quantity,
                categoryfilter: categoryfilter,
                description: description,
                timestamp: timestamp
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

here's the error on the client side after the request.

[image]

Comment: What is the origin of the server (its host and port)? What request is sent to what URL?

Comment: it's port localhost:5000 and the request is patch request im not sure where is the conflict on my code...someone told me the problem was on client side and others are on server side ..

Comment: `PATCH` is an HTTP verb, I don't mean that. I mean [the request itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_syntax): the verb ("patch"), the URL (a full one, including origin and query), headers, maybe payload (if it's relevant and not gigantic).

Comment: You can see it in the DevTools in the "Network" tab; open the tab, then send the request again (in that order)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple endpoints using the same HTTP verb in a router. [it will only match the first applicable route](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html).
Not sure about what's going on. Let's do the trivial fist:

1. Is your router being used by the app? `app.use(router)` Make sure these `patch` routes are being looked up.
2. Is there any other route matching the endpoint?
3. Is there an endpoint sending status 404 first? `res.sendStatus(404)`
4. Isn't it any typo problem?

Hope this gives an insight

Comment: I'm quite sure that my endpoints are correct. the thing that i'm not sure whether the client side or server side is giving me the error. is it possible that the main cause of 404 is the data that I'm sending ?

Comment: A 404 error is a client fault. It's likely the client is targeting the wrong route / verb. It can also be thrown by the error handler if no routes are matched. Also, you may be throwing a 404 if a resource hasn't been found in your records. Eg: /admin/collections/view/9999 -> not found in DB, send 404